# capture group via regex and then split capture groups into separate list items

Tags: python, regex, split

I have readlines into a list:

```
l =  ['W –-Transportation',
     'W23.F5-International_waterways                      W25.2-Airlines',
     'W23.F8-Rivers                                       W25.4-Bus_lines',
     'W23.H-Pipelines                                       W25.6-Railroads',
     'W23.H2-Oil_pipelines                                W25.8-Shipping_lines',
     'W23.H4-Natural_gas_pipelines                        W27-Transportation_safety',
     'W23.H6-Water_pipelines                              W27.2-Traffic_safety',
     'W23.K-Transportation_system_design                    W29-Navigation',
     'W23.M-Transportation_system_construction              W32-Transportation_research',
     'W23.M2-Transportation_facility_construction         W32.2-Transportation_surveys',
     'W23.M4-Transportation_system_maintenance            W34-Transportation_education',
     'W23.M4.2-Road_maintenance                        W36-Transportation_policy',
     'W23.M6-Transportation_system_repair                 W38-Transportation_planning',
     'W23.M6.2-Vehicle_repair                          W40-Transportation_aspects',
     'W25-Transportation_industry']
```

Now for each line, I want to capture 2 groups e.g.- `W23.F5-International_waterways` and `W25.2-Airlines` and separate them into two list entries.

My expected results are:

```
l =  ['W –-Transportation','W23.F5-International_waterways','W25.2-Airlines','W23.F8-Rivers','W25.4-Bus_lines','W23.H-Pipelines','W25.6-Railroads','W23.H2-Oil_pipelines','W25.8-Shipping_lines', .....,'W25-Transportation_industry']
```

The regex for capturing groups would be `([a-z])\s*?([A-Z])` but how should I split the capture groups into new list entries?

Comment: post the expected result

Comment: What about items like `'W –-Transportation'` or `'W25-Transportation_industry'`? In general, you just need to split each item with `\s+`, as each value only consists of non-whitespaces.

Comment: Added the expected results.

Comment: The regex that you show wouldn't capture those strings.  Is there a reason that you want to use regex and groups for this?  It might be much simpler to just use `.split()` on each line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe, a simple split on a `"  "` might work just OK here:

```
import re

l =  ['W –-Transportation',
     'W23.F5-International_waterways                      W25.2-Airlines',
     'W23.F8-Rivers                                       W25.4-Bus_lines',
     'W23.H-Pipelines                                       W25.6-Railroads',
     'W23.H2-Oil_pipelines                                W25.8-Shipping_lines',
     'W23.H4-Natural_gas_pipelines                        W27-Transportation_safety',
     'W23.H6-Water_pipelines                              W27.2-Traffic_safety',
     'W23.K-Transportation_system_design                    W29-Navigation',
     'W23.M-Transportation_system_construction              W32-Transportation_research',
     'W23.M2-Transportation_facility_construction         W32.2-Transportation_surveys',
     'W23.M4-Transportation_system_maintenance            W34-Transportation_education',
     'W23.M4.2-Road_maintenance                        W36-Transportation_policy',
     'W23.M6-Transportation_system_repair                 W38-Transportation_planning',
     'W23.M6.2-Vehicle_repair                          W40-Transportation_aspects',
     'W25-Transportation_industry']

k = []
for i in l:
    new_string = i.split("  ")
    for j in new_string:
        if j != '':
            k.append(j.strip())


print(k)
```

#### Output

```
['W –-Transportation', 'W23.F5-International_waterways', 'W25.2-Airlines', 'W23.F8-Rivers', 'W25.4-Bus_lines', 'W23.H-Pipelines', 'W25.6-Railroads', 'W23.H2-Oil_pipelines', 'W25.8-Shipping_lines', 'W23.H4-Natural_gas_pipelines', 'W27-Transportation_safety', 'W23.H6-Water_pipelines', 'W27.2-Traffic_safety', 'W23.K-Transportation_system_design', 'W29-Navigation', 'W23.M-Transportation_system_construction', 'W32-Transportation_research', 'W23.M2-Transportation_facility_construction', 'W32.2-Transportation_surveys', 'W23.M4-Transportation_system_maintenance', 'W34-Transportation_education', 'W23.M4.2-Road_maintenance', 'W36-Transportation_policy', 'W23.M6-Transportation_system_repair', 'W38-Transportation_planning', 'W23.M6.2-Vehicle_repair', 'W40-Transportation_aspects', 'W25-Transportation_industry']
```